# MATLAB fitensemble : How it build each tree ? Based on all features OR subset of features?

Tags: matlab, random-forest

I am using fitensemble function with 'Bag' in matlab 2011b for classification using following:

**fitensemble(features , classLabels,'Bag',10,'tree','type' , 'classification');**

Can someone inform how fitensemble select features for building each decision tree? Does it select  a subset of all features for each tree ( as like original Breiman's random-forest) ? Or it select all features to build each tree?

For example, if thee are 500 features in data set, does every tree is built based on 500 features OR a subset of 500 features are selected randomly for building each tree?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `NVarToSample` property of `ClassificationTree.template` and `Regressiontree.template`. You can set it to either a positive integer or 'all'. By default, for classification `fitensemble` uses 'all' for boosting and the square root of the number of variables for bagging (your situation). For regression, it uses 'all' for boosting and 1/3 the number of variables for bagging.